# How to keep the first part of a name if differents species name in big dataset R

Tags: r, database, filter, selection, data-cleaning

I have to clean up a data table in R and I'm stuck on a point

I'm searching about how i can be specific in a table by keeping the first part of a species name (before the "_" and add ".sp") if its not specific.

Its better if i show you an example :

I have a table like this :

```
reads |            species
ST311 | cylindrotheca_closterium 
ST311  | cylindrotheca_fusiformis
ST311  | cylindrotheca_fusiformis
ST311 | cylindrotheca_fusiformis
ST311  | cylindrotheca_closterium
ST312 | alexandrium_minutum
ST317 |pseudo.nitzschia_australis
```

At the end, I just need if there are different species for the same read and the same genus, here its cylindrotheca for example: for all the species for this read "ST311" put: "cylindrotheca_sp".

if a read is specific for example ST312 for alexandrium minutum and ST317 for pseudo nitzschia australis i want to keep it.

This is my expected table :

```
reads |            species
ST311 | cylindrotheca_sp 
ST311  | cylindrotheca_sp
ST311  | cylindrotheca_sp
ST311 | cylindrotheca_sp
ST311  | cylindrotheca_sp
ST312 | alexandrium_minutum
ST317 |pseudo.nitzschia_australis
```

I thought something like that: (i know its wrong...But there is the idea)

```
TEST <-prim51test %>% 
  group_by(read) %>%
  if(species > 1){
  print == "*_sp"
  }
```

(I have a big dataset with a lot of different species)

How could I do that?

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1):

You can use `sub` to remove everything after underscore and replace with `'_sp'`.

```
df$new_species <- sub("_.*", "_sp", df$species)
df

#  reads                  species      new_species
#1 ST311 cylindrotheca_closterium cylindrotheca_sp
#2 ST311 cylindrotheca_fusiformis cylindrotheca_sp
#3 ST311 cylindrotheca_fusiformis cylindrotheca_sp
#4 ST311 cylindrotheca_fusiformis cylindrotheca_sp
#5 ST311 cylindrotheca_closterium cylindrotheca_sp
```

---

For the updated condition you can try :

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  add_count(reads) %>%
  mutate(species = ifelse(n > 1, sub("_.*", "_sp", species), species)) %>%
  select(-n) -> df
df

#  reads                   species
#1 ST311          cylindrotheca_sp
#2 ST311          cylindrotheca_sp
#3 ST311          cylindrotheca_sp
#4 ST311          cylindrotheca_sp
#5 ST311          cylindrotheca_sp
#6 ST312       alexandrium minutum
#7 ST314 pseudonitzschia_australis
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(reads = c("ST311", "ST311", "ST311", "ST311", 
"ST311"), species = c("cylindrotheca_closterium", "cylindrotheca_fusiformis", 
"cylindrotheca_fusiformis", "cylindrotheca_fusiformis", "cylindrotheca_closterium"
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))
```

Comment: thank you very much ! But how i can do that just if species are differents and not always ? Because if i can i would have the species names

Comment: Some reads have just one species or the same for all, in this case its ok, but sometimes like the example i just want to change in the column "species" the names of them for one single term (with .sp at the end). Do you know how to solve that ? Thank you... I m not really experienced in R

Comment: @Lpr You can change the same column by using `df$species <- sub("_.*", "_sp", df$species)`. Did you try the answer? What does it return?

Comment: Hello, when i do that its give me the .sp everywhere,  I need to have one read environmental = one species at the end and i would like when its different species to go back to the taxonomic level and put .sp. but not always just when species are differents for one read.

Comment: @Lpr Show a better example then. Right now my answer gives the expected output that you have shown in your new post.

Comment: df <- structure(list(reads = c("ST311", "ST311", "ST311", "ST311", 
"ST311", "ST312","ST314"), species = c("cylindrotheca_closterium", "cylindrotheca_fusiformis", 
"cylindrotheca_fusiformis", "cylindrotheca_fusiformis", "cylindrotheca_closterium", "alexandrium minutum", "pseudonitzschia_australis"
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -7L)). For example here, i  would like to keep my last two species without the sp.

Comment: @Lpr What would be your expected output for this data? Can you update your post with it?

Comment: i update it, thank you very much for your help

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you want to replace for each *read* the name (i.e. the suffix) of those species whose suffixes are unique.

At first you could make a table on pre and suffices using `gsub`. This gives here a 3x2x2 array `A` that we  turn to logical class using `> 1`.  From the `colSums` *cs* we want to know for each column which of the `rownames` has value *1*. Giving a named matching vector `m` that we send through a `Map` over *reads* and *species*, where we replace the suffixes of matches with `"_sp"` using `<<-`.

```
A <- with(d, table(gsub(".*_", "", species), gsub("_.*", "", species), reads)) > 1
(cs <- colSums(A, 3))
#              reads
#               ST311 ST312
# ceratoneis        1     0
# cylindrotheca     2     1
m <- apply(cs, 2, function(x) rownames(cs)[which(x == 1)])
invisible(Map(function(i, j) {
  d$species[d$reads %in% i & grepl(j, d$species)] <<- paste0(j, "_sp")
  }, names(m), m))
d
#    reads                  species
# 1  ST311 cylindrotheca_closterium
# 2  ST311 cylindrotheca_fusiformis
# 3  ST311 cylindrotheca_fusiformis
# 4  ST311 cylindrotheca_fusiformis
# 5  ST311 cylindrotheca_closterium
# 6  ST311            ceratoneis_sp
# 7  ST311            ceratoneis_sp
# 8  ST312     ceratoneis_reimannii
# 9  ST312         cylindrotheca_sp
# 10 ST312    ceratoneis_closterium
# 11 ST312         cylindrotheca_sp
# 12 ST312         cylindrotheca_sp
```

---

*Data:*

*Note:* I extended the data at will to prepare code for best scalability.

```
d <- structure(list(reads = c("ST311", "ST311", "ST311", "ST311", 
"ST311", "ST311", "ST311", "ST312", "ST312", "ST312", "ST312", 
"ST312"), species = c("cylindrotheca_closterium", "cylindrotheca_fusiformis", 
"cylindrotheca_fusiformis", "cylindrotheca_fusiformis", "cylindrotheca_closterium", 
"ceratoneis_reimannii", "ceratoneis_reimannii", "ceratoneis_reimannii", 
"cylindrotheca_fusiformis", "ceratoneis_closterium", "cylindrotheca_fusiformis", 
"cylindrotheca_fusiformis")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-12L))
```